# .net core Soap server Response

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, soap, .net-core

I used `.net core 2.2` to response a sample Soap request like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">      
  <soap:Header>
    <UserCredentials xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <userName>string</userName>
      <password>string</password>
    </UserCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSubxmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <value>10</value>
    </GetSub>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but I don't know how to get `userName` , `password`.

I search a lot but not found a clearly solution ,So Can Some one help me?!

**Notice:** 
I can't edit my request model !!